# Missing Stored Procedures in Linked Server view within SSMS

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2019

Why am I unable to see Stored Procedures or functions when I open a Linked Server in SSMS? I have created the Linked Server and can see the databases, but within each database, only tables and views are shown.

[Linked Servers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m9Af.jpg)

in Linked Server Properties
Provider: Microsoft OLEDB Provider for SQL Server
Log in: Be made using the login's current security context
RPC, RPC out in Server Options is true

Comment: You may not have any permissions on these objects.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is how it works. Only tables and views are shown under the \Catalogs folder.
At least on SQLserver linking MySQL/SQLserver /Oracle no matter the "mapped login" server roles.

What appears under Catalogs is what the following query returns:

```
   EXEC sys.sp_tables_ex @table_server='LinkedServer', @table_catalog='databasename'
```

Comment: The Linked Server is connected to another SQL Server instance installed on another Server, I expected to see too Programmability folder and within it the Stored procedures and functions